# Oracle SQL: How to modify query in order to get only results within a certain timeframe?

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I use this statement in Oracle SQL Developer

```
select to_char(time,'DD/MM/YY hh24'),count(column) as xyz from table
where to_char(time,'DD/MM/YY')>= '08/04/21'
and to_char(time,'DD/MM/YY')<= '09/04/21'
and column='xyz'
group by to_char(time,'DD/MM/YY hh24')
order by to_char(time,'DD/MM/YY hh24');
```

What I expect is a result/table in which the result is ordered by time in ascending order (starting with the earliest hour on `08/04/21` and ending with the latest on `09/04/21`. I would expect only entries for days `08/04/21` and `09/04/21`. Instead, I get a result where also other dates are included like `09/02/21` or `08/12/20`.

How can I modify my query?

Comment: Can you include some sample data for your table?

Comment: For the resulting table or for the actual one for which I run the query?

Comment: Well both, but at least sample data for the original table.

Comment: you can change all the date formats you return to 'YYYY/MM/DD' otherwise they do not compare according to date order.  Also your use of YY risks a Y2K problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are converting your native date values to strings (with two-digit years!) and then comparing those strings. The string '08/12/20' is 'less than' the string '09/04/21'.

Compare your dates with other dates, which is easier as literals:

```
select to_char(trunc(time, 'HH'), 'DD/MM/YY HH24'), count(column) as xyz
from table
where time >= date '2021-04-08'
and time < date '2021-04-10'
and column='xyz'
group by trunc(time, 'HH')
order by trunc(time, 'HH');
```

I've used `trunc()` to remove/zero the minute and seconds parts, which means you can then group and order by that value; and just convert to a string for display at the last moment.

I've also converted `to_char(time,'DD/MM/YY')<= '09/04/21'` to `time < date '2021-04-10'` rather than `time < date '2021-04-09'`as your version include all data from the 9th; which may or may not be what you intended - you might have been trying to get a single day.

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=bc3a40cd1da9f534ea10330d1e365d57)

Comment: Thanks a lot! This solved it. But one question: I wanted to include 09/04/2021. But when using `and creationtime <= date '2021-04-09'` the rows for 09/04/21 are not included when using your solution. Why is this the case?

Comment: Because `date '2021-04-09'` is midnight on the 9th, i.e. 2021-04-09 00:00:00; so anything later than exactly midnight is not matched, even 2021-04-09 00:00:01. That's why I changed to `< date '2021-04-10'` - that includes everything up to, but not including, midnight on the 10th - and thus includes all times on the 9th.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot for your explanation and help :-)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `time` is of data type `date`, you don't want to do a `to_char` on it in your `where` clause or in your `order by`.  As written, you're doing string comparisons rather than date comparisons so you're getting rows where the `to_char(time` string sorts alphabetically between the two values not rows where the date is between the two dates.  Compare against date literals or do explicit `to_date` calls on your string literals

My wager is that you really want something like this

```
select trunc(time, 'HH24'),count(column) as xyz 
  from table
 where time >= date '2021-08-04'
   and time <= date '2021-09-04'
   and column='xyz'
 group by trunc(time, 'HH24')
 order by trunc(time, 'HH24');
```